# Merge all data of parent child relation-ship from same table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a one table like this

[image: id value tire 1 2 10 1 1 5 2 3 10]

I expect to create table like this this

[image]

*yellow color is header sum of value or tire

I try with union an join but still not valid

any suggest for this problem. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP` is what you want here:

```sql
SELECT id, SUM(value), SUM(tire)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id, value WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY -id DESC, SUM(value) DESC;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: try this i get error : Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP and ORDER BY